# Получаю ошибку No webdriver is bound to current thread 1 you need to call open url first в тестах для android

Tags: java, android, appium, selenide

Всем привет в лаборатории, дали задачу реализовать проект для мобильного автотестирования, собрал проект по тому что было в интернете, но при запуске тестов получаю ошибку

```
 No webdriver is bound to current thread: 1. You need to call open(url) first.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No webdriver is bound to current thread: 1. You need to call open(url) first.
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.lambda$getWebDriver$1(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:144)
```

В чем моя ошибка, подскажите те кто знает или уже сталкивался, буду очень признателен.
Хочу отметить еще то что, приложение стартует после запуска теста, возможно проблема в локаторе, но решения пока не нашел.

Прикрепляю код инициализации драйвера и тестового класса :

```
 @Slf4j
public abstract class BaseTest {

    @BeforeAll
    public static void initialize() throws MalformedURLException {
        Configuration.browser = "deviceHost";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(DEVICE_NAME, "Pixel 2 API 30 Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability(PLATFORM_NAME, "android");
        capabilities.setCapability(APP_PACKAGE, "ru.astondevs.powerbank");
        capabilities.setCapability(APP_ACTIVITY, "ru.astondevs.powerbank.MainActivity");

//        capabilities.setCapability(DEVICE_NAME,"deviceName");
//        capabilities.setCapability(PLATFORM_NAME,"platformName");
//        capabilities.setCapability(APP_PACKAGE,"appPackage");
//        capabilities.setCapability(APP_ACTIVITY, "appActivity");
//        capabilities.setCapability(APP, "app");

        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);


//        try {
//            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("remoteUrl"), capabilities);
//            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
//            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
//        }

    }

public class AuthPageTest extends BaseTest {
    AuthPage authPage = new AuthPage();

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Проверка состояния кнопки войти")
    public void enterAuthButtonTest() {
        step("Проверить что кнопка \"войти\" присутствует на экране", () -> {
            authPage.authButton.shouldBe(Condition.exist);
        });
    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: В ошибке вроде все четко сказано. Попробуйте вчитаться в нее.

Comment: В ошибке сказано что нужно вызвать первым методом открытие урла, это понимаю. Но я понимаю когда это применимо к веб приложению, но если используется приложения android, то не совсем ясно(